# PHP Using domdocument to extract data from html

Tags: php

I have a table with the following structure. I cannot seem to get the data I want.

```
<table class="gsborder" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="2" rules="cols" border="1" id="d00">
    <tr class="gridItem">
        <td>Code</td><td>0adf</td>
    </tr><tr class="AltItem">
        <td>CompanyName</td><td>Some Company</td>
    </tr><tr class="Item">
        <td>Owner</td><td>Jim Jim</td>
    </tr><tr class="AltItem">
        <td>DivisionName</td><td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr><tr class="Item">
        <td>AddressLine1</td><td>9314 W. SPRING ST.</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This table is of course nested within another table within the page. How can I use DomDocument for example to refer to "Code" and "0adf" as a key value pair? They actually don't need to be in a key value pair but I should be able to call them each separately.

EDIT:

Using PHP Simple HTML, I was able to extract the data I needed using this:

```
  $foo = $html->getElementById("d00")->childNodes(1)->childNodes(1);
```

The problem with this though is that I am getting the two `<td></td>` tags with my data. Is there a way to only grab the raw data without the tags?

Also, is this the right way to get my data out of this table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're not dead set on using DOMDocument, try using the [PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/). This has the benefit of allowing you to parse HTML which is not valid XML as well as providing a nicer interface to the parsed document.

You could write something like:

```
$html = str_get_html(...);
foreach($html->find('tr') as $tr) 
{
  print 'First td: ' . $tr->find('td', 0)->plaintext;
  print 'Second td: ' . $tr->find('td', 1)->plaintext;
}
```

Comment: Hi Andrew, I'm not set on it at all actually. I'm only using this to transfer over some data. So, the way I am working this now is importing the document with simplexml. I'm assuming that the str_get_html() takes care of grabbing the contents, yes?

Comment: So str_get_html() parses HTML data from a string, you can use file_get_html() to read from a file or URL and perhaps avoid using simplexml altogether?

Comment: Yep.. This will do exactly what I need. Thanks Andrew!

Comment: I just tossed simplexml out. I like this much better. :)  This is certainly more straightforward than simplexml and has better documentation.

Comment: Andrew, are you still around? I cannot get this working... I was wondering of you wouldn't mind having a look at what I have.

Comment: Ah, great! Thanks Andrew.. I'll post it above in my original post. I'm not sure if this is the "optimal" way of doing it but it semi works.

Comment: Or start another question. You might get help from others as well if you do that.